# What is the latest official version of XJC and where can I get it?

Tags: java, xml, jaxb, xjc

*XJC* (XML Java Compiler) is part of *JAXB* (Java XML Bindings).

If I look at the [official website](https://jaxb.java.net), the latest version of *JAXB* seems to be **2.2.11**. That's the one you got when you just install the latest JDK version **8u40**.

The following output shows the version of *XJC* related to JDK 8u40:

```
../JDK8u40/bin$ ./javac -version
javac 1.8.0_40
../JDK8u40/bin$ ./xjc -version
xjc 2.2.8-b130911.1802
```

(The original JDK path differs from OS to OS, so this is just an exemplary representation.)

It seems the version of *XJC* differs to the "latest" *JAXB* version or the latest JDK does not contain the latest JAXB version.

My workaround is to just install the latest JAXB version from the [Maven repository](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.xml.bind/jaxb-api). Sounds easy, but why the latest version of JAXB is **2.2.12** now? Forgot to put the documentation on the offical website? Okay, I just try to don't care... After the successful installation process I noticed there is no *XJC* inside this package. So go on searching... I found another Maven repository with the name "[JAXB-XJC](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.glassfish.jaxb/jaxb-xjc)". But this is just the source code. I simply want to install the latest binary of *XJC*. I looked at the version number, which is **2.2.11**. That looks at least better than 2.2.8.

**But where I can get the latest binary of *XJC*?**

Why I want to install the latest binary of *XJC*? Because I want to know if it supports Optionals of Java 8 and/or if it supports XSD schema version 1.1. Somewhere on the Internet I read the latest *XJC* at least supports the XSD schema version 1.1. That would be enough for now. But to figure this out, it seems Oracle has to fix their horrible version chaos.

**Update**

I tried to build JAXB by cloning the official [Git repository](https://github.com/gf-metro/jaxb) and doing `mvn clean install`.

Result:

```
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Reactor Summary:
[INFO] 
[INFO] JAXB BOM ........................................... SUCCESS [  0.140 s]
[INFO] JAXB BOM with ALL dependencies ..................... SUCCESS [  0.005 s]
[INFO] JAXB Reference Implementation ...................... SUCCESS [  0.515 s]
[INFO] JAXB External parent ............................... SUCCESS [  0.009 s]
[INFO] RNGOM .............................................. SUCCESS [  3.723 s]
[INFO] Codemodel .......................................... SUCCESS [  0.008 s]
[INFO] Codemodel Core ..................................... SUCCESS [  2.622 s]
[INFO] Codemodel Annotation Compiler ...................... SUCCESS [  0.848 s]
[INFO] JAXB TXW parent .................................... SUCCESS [  0.006 s]
[INFO] TXW2 Runtime ....................................... SUCCESS [  1.920 s]
[INFO] TXW2 Compiler ...................................... SUCCESS [  1.507 s]
[INFO] JAXB Core .......................................... SUCCESS [  1.745 s]
[INFO] JAXB Runtime parent ................................ SUCCESS [  0.008 s]
[INFO] JAXB Runtime ....................................... SUCCESS [  5.932 s]
[INFO] JAXB1 Runtime ...................................... SUCCESS [  1.520 s]
[INFO] JAXB XJC ........................................... SUCCESS [  5.555 s]
[INFO] JAXB JXC ........................................... SUCCESS [  2.928 s]
[INFO] Parent for osgi testing modules. ................... SUCCESS [  0.009 s]
[INFO] osgi-test-parent ................................... SUCCESS [  1.315 s]
[INFO] osgi-test-core ..................................... SUCCESS [  0.676 s]
[INFO] JAXB bundles ....................................... SUCCESS [  0.007 s]
[INFO] Old JAXB Core ...................................... SUCCESS [  4.669 s]
[INFO] osgi-test-runtime .................................. SUCCESS [  0.677 s]
[INFO] Old JAXB Runtime ................................... SUCCESS [  3.251 s]
[INFO] osgi-test-xjc ...................................... SUCCESS [  0.637 s]
[INFO] Old JAXB XJC ....................................... SUCCESS [  4.385 s]
[INFO] osgi-test-jxc ...................................... SUCCESS [  0.607 s]
[INFO] Old JAXB JXC ....................................... SUCCESS [  2.169 s]
[INFO] JAXB Documentation parent .......................... SUCCESS [  0.005 s]
[INFO] JAXB Release Documentation ......................... SUCCESS [ 12.401 s]
[INFO] JAXB samples ....................................... SUCCESS [  0.375 s]
[INFO] JAXB RI ............................................ SUCCESS [  1.079 s]
[INFO] JAXB OSGI parent ................................... SUCCESS [  0.005 s]
[INFO] JAXB extra OSGI .................................... FAILURE [  6.668 s]
[INFO] JAXB OSGI .......................................... SKIPPED
[INFO] osgi-test-osgi ..................................... SKIPPED
[INFO] osgi-test-extra_osgi ............................... SKIPPED
[INFO] JAXB OSGi Tests .................................... SKIPPED
[INFO] JAXB WWW Help files ................................ SKIPPED
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 01:08 min
[INFO] Finished at: 2015-03-11T15:40:59+01:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 83M/1546M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-shade-plugin:2.0:shade (default) on project jaxb-extra-osgi: Error creating shaded jar: java.util.jar.Attributes cannot be cast to java.lang.String -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] After correcting the problems, you can resume the build with the command
[ERROR]   mvn <goals> -rf :jaxb-extra-osgi
```

The build process always fails at the *JAXB extra OSGI* target. The *JAXB XJC* target builds successfully, but only contains a exceptions throwing jar file but no binary named *xjc*. So where is it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've fixed OSGi failures within JAXB maven build. So now it should be OK.

Additionally to have fast build you can try to use:

```
$ mvn clean install -Ddev
```

This will run fast build without creating docs/osgi-tests.

Also you can find legacy `jaxb-ri.zip` (with bin/ libs/ examples/) within `$JAXB_HOME/bundles/ri/target/`. Or if you don't want every time to unzip it after the build go directly to: `$JAXB_HOME/bundles/ri/target/stage/jaxb-ri/`.

PS: don't forget to use [JAVA endorsed mechanism](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/standards/) for jaxb-api.jar if you are using standalone JAXB.